# jasmin hacking and verify error

Tags: java, verifyerror, jasmin

I'm playing with jasmin and I try to launch my .class file, which is supposed to perform simple string concatenation. My jasmin source looks like this:

```
.class public default_class
.super java/lang/Object
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit locals 1
.limit stack 1
invokestatic main_65428301()I
return
.end method
.method public static main_65428301()I
.limit locals 1
.limit stack 100
new java/lang/String
dup
ldc "foo"
invokestatic java/lang/String.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc "bar"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/String.toString()V
astore_0
iconst_0
ireturn
.end method
```

Now I'm able to run java -jar jasmin.jar and I get default_class.class. However, when I try to launch it like java default_class I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: default_class, method: main_65428301 signature: ()I) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

What should I change in my assembly to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JVM, to create the object you have to first use `new` instruction and then call `<init>` method (constructor). You do not create `new` StringBuilder and call the wrong constructor name (should be `java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V`).

I also see no reason to do:

```
new java/lang/String
dup
```

or

```
invokestatic java/lang/String.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: I tried to mimic what eclipse do in similar situation, but thanks for pointing this out. Anyway I'd like to know what's wrong with invocation of my second main-like method, because that's what error message suggest

Comment: @k_wisniewski, In my opinion it refers to `invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder(Ljava/lang/String;)V`, which is inside `(class: default_class, method: main_65428301 signature: ()I)`

Comment: OK, I got rid of this problem now

Answer (score 0):

"The new instruction does not completely create a new instance; instance initialization is not completed until an instance initialization method has been invoked on the uninitialized instance."